# Check if something is mounted

Tags: linux, mount

I want to check if something is mounted or not in `/mnt/MyCloud`. I tried:

- `if mountpoint -q /mnt/MyCloud; then`
- `if mountpoint -q "/mnt/MyCloud"; then`
- Edit: `if mount | grep /mnt/MyCloud > /dev/null; then`

Both go to `else` (returns false I guess)

What is the proper way to check such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the `mountpoint` man page:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> Zero if the directory or file is a mountpoint, non-zero if not.

By your snippet I'd say the check is done correctly. Furthermore, I tried it with a `mountpoint` of mine and it returns what is expected.

```
#!/bin/bash

if mountpoint -q /home; then
  echo "It's a mountpoint"
fi
```

When run, the code prints the phrase. If you're not getting this behavior, I'd:

- Check if the package that contains `mountpoint` is corrupt.
- Check the `man` page of your command. The return code might differ between different distributions.
- Check if it's *actually* a mountpoint. You can run a bare `mount` command and check if it's listed among the currently mounted points. Note that a non-mounted point will return a non-zero code as per the documentation, even if the directory/file exists.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like it is not a mount point at all. I ran this script - https://github.com/Zacho2/PiCloud/blob/master/picloud.sh - lines 40-44 are mounting my NAS to /mnt/MyCloud, and if I go to /mnt/MyCloud and creates a file, it does create it on the NAS, so im not sure why "mount" does not list it.

Comment: Having a quick look at the code, it appends the line to the `/etc/fstab` file but does not mount it. You need to mount it manually, either specifying the mountpoint via `mount /mnt/MyCloud` or mounting all your points with `mount -a`.

Comment: Ok, so `mount -a` is the way to go, unfortunetly, the device is busy and is used by PID `kernel`, so it will not mount